# the function to update table values based on values entered in another page

Tags: javascript, html

I am facing the following problem

I am creating two web pages like for example in job applications when ask you to add new skills or new language. I linked the first page with the second. One of the problem is that, I want to insert some data in the second page and then update the table in the first page based on the values entered in the second page.
The following code is for first page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Syrian Sanction
    </title>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: bisque;
        }
        table{
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            text-align: center;
        }
        td{
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        th{
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>sources of fund</h1>
    <table>
        <th>sources of fund</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Use Evaluation Set</th>
        <tr>
            <td>WFP</td>
            <td>UN</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>UNFPA</td>
            <td>UN</td>
            <td>1</td> 
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">add source of fund</button>
    <hr>
    
    <div>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="First_Page.html">Next page</a>
    </div>
    
<script>
function myFunction() {
  location.replace("Untitled-1.html")
}
</script>
</body>
```

The code for the second page is:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>new page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <select>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="1">4</option>
 </select>
 <select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="1">4</option>
 </select>
 <select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="1">4</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button onclick="">Add values </button>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: It's not impossible to handle, but not really a good idea to share state between different pages with javascript. What you can do is to have two different divs containing each page which you show/hide depending on what page you want to view.

Comment: thank you could you please help me with this , could you please show me the code

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your website needs to share a variable or two, between two or more pages.
Here’s how...

Create a “**Shared.js**” text file and move your global variables to it and then add this line to the HEAD section of all pages that need access to these variables:

```
 <script src="Shared.js"></script>
```

Now you should be able to read/write from/to these variables from multiple pages.

Comment: thank you so much could you give me more details please this issue is urgent for me

Comment: The instructions I offered should suffice. I have nothing else to add.

Comment: i donz't undestand but anyway thank you so much for your time